# Making a batch file wait until the shutdown command called by a Perl script (which is called by the batch file) gets executed

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which calls a Perl script and then the Perl script which does some processing and then executes a command `shutdown /r /t 1`.
In the batch file after the Perl is called, there is exit `/b`. For instance:

Batch file:

```
perl doSomething.pl

exit /b
```

Perl file:

```
do stuff

shutdown /r /t 1
```

I want the batch file to not exit and wait until the shutdown begins.

I have tried

```
start /wait perl dosomething.pl
```

and looping with tasklist to check for `perl.exe` and exit only if `perl.exe` process has finished. Nothing worked.

Is there a solution to achieve this without 'sleeping' or infinite loop wait until shutdown?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. The batch file won't execute anything after `perl` before `perl` exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's strange. It simply HAS to work with the last option, you've mentioned (checking the task list).

However, the only option I can think of is to create a kind of flag file. Let your perl script create a file somewhere just before it terminates and make your bat loop around until this file is found and delete it before terminating. To avoid "busy waiting" you could add something like `ping localhost -n 6 >nul` inside your bat loop.

Comment: I think the task list thing  isn't working because even the perl exits before the shutdown is initiated. I am not allowed to make changes in the perl file so it won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get the meaning of " because even the perl exits before the shutdown is initiated".

Comment: Perl:

`some stuff`

`shutdown \r \t 1`

`exit`

So when the command shutdown is called, before shutdown is executed due to 1 sec timeout the Perl exits. So I am not able to find it in tasklist

Comment: I'm not really familiar with perl. `shutdown \r \t 1` calls `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe`, doesn't it? How about having your bat script wait for shutdown.exe to appear in the tasklist and exit after it disappears?